# How to convert a string to jquery object?

Tags: jquery-templates, jquery

I am using jquery template for my project. The problem I am facing is that when rendering a template I am converting `$data` to string and passing it in onclick function [see the code below].

```
<script id="Item" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li id="${ID}" class="card red ui-state-default">
        <a class="desc" href="" onclick="return $$.popup.eItem('${($data)}');"> ${$data.Desc} </a> 
    </li>
</script>
```

the converting of `$data` object to string and passing it to a function

```
onclick="return $$.popup.eItem('${($data)}');"
```

here, `$data` is an object containing the actual data. And when I click the link I get the passed string as `"[object Object]"` and I want to convert it again back to jquery object so I can use it in my code.

I can use 'JSON.stringify()' to convert the `$data` object to JSON, like this

```
onclick="return $$.popup.editCard('${JSON.stringify($data)}');"
```

but as the template is rendered to html, this is the output:

```
<a class="desc" href="" onclick="return $$.popup.eItem('{&quot;TemplateName&quot;:&quot;CardItem&quot;,&quot;ID&quot;:&quot;lc822&quot;,&quot;Desc&quot;:&quot;make card EntityAssignId = 0&quot;,&quot;CardId&quot;:822,&quot;LaneId&quot;:665,&quot;Priority&quot;:1,&quot;AssignedEntityId&quot;:0,&quot;Pic&quot;:null,&quot;SortOrder&quot;:2}');">make card EntityAssignId = 0</a>
```

So any suggestion?

Comment: yup I did, but then it didn't renders the template ...

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your question but have you tried `$( document.createTextNode( ... ) )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to access the properties of the data object maybe you should access them:

```
 onclick="return $$.popup.eItem('${($data.ID)}');"
```

In this way you will get the ID property. You get "[object Object]" because that's the way that javascript uses to convert an object tio a string (you would get the same if you called `alert($data);`

From your expample I would expect my code to be converted to

```
<a class="desc" href="" onclick="return $$.popup.eItem('lc822');">make card EntityAssignId = 0</a>
```

because from your "Stringified" code i can see that the property `ID` of `$data` is equal to lc822

Comment: I know I can do that, but I want to pass whole object so I can assign values straight away, instead of making a DB call and getting the rest of the data from it ... but if I don't any other option I'll pass ID and make a DB call to get the related data ...

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
console.log($('<div>').append( $data ).remove().html());
```

Hope this helps.